How to Set the Frame Rate for GLKView or MTKView on iPhone 15 Pro Max (120Hz Display)?
I’m trying to define the frame rate for rendering with a GLKView or MTKView on my iPhone 15 Pro Max, which supports a 120Hz refresh rate (ProMotion). However, I’m having difficulty achieving anything higher than 60 FPS. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
For GLKView: By default, drawRect is called at a maximum rate of 60 FPS, despite the device being capable of 120 FPS.
For MTKView: I’ve set enableSetNeedsDisplay to true and manually call setNeedsDisplay every 8ms, expecting it to render at around 120 FPS. However, the frame rate remains capped at 60 FPS.
How can I configure either GLKView or MTKView to render at the device's full 120Hz capability? Are there additional settings or properties (e.g., related to CADisplayLink or preferredFramesPerSecond) that I need to adjust for high refresh rates?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Enable faster ProMotion refresh rates

Yes but what do do exactly ? i did everything without success

I found, i need to do :
let displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(render))
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    displayLink.preferredFrameRateRange = CAFrameRateRange(minimum: 120, maximum: 120, preferred: 120)
} else {
    displayLink.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60
}
displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: .default)

